# Where do i check the thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i got a table showing some product information and a product image for Woo Commerce. Now i have changed my website out the sub-directory to the main directory and somehow the thumbnail pictures don't work. I tried regenerating them but without success.

```
<tr>
                <td style="width: auto;">
                    <div style="padding: 15px;">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank" class="thumbnail alignleft"><img src="<?php
                            if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID))
                            {
                                $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail');
                                echo woof_aq_resize($img_src[0], get_tpl_option('tpl_2_img_width', $options), get_tpl_option('tpl_2_img_height', $options), true);
                            } else
                            {
                                echo WOOF_LINK . 'img/not-found.jpg';
                            }
                            ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?>" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </td>
```

This is where it gets the information to get the image and i was wondering if this is doing something wrong or if there is any other way to fix this issue.
Issue is at http://www.zilvertron.com/motoren/ you can see that it shows the title instead of a thumbnail image.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you have move out of the subdirectory, you have to search for the old path and replace it with the new path in the whole database. Did you do this? [The perfect tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) for this task.

Comment: Hmm i need a little more information to do this, if you mean i need to replace the files like wp-content?

Comment: Here is the most usefull tools to do this :
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail');
echo woof_aq_resize($img_src[0], get_tpl_option('tpl_2_img_width', $options), get_tpl_option('tpl_2_img_height', $options), true);
```

with this:

```
$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'single-post-thumbnail');
echo '$img_src[0]';
```

Let me know if this prints out the image. Basically this is a first step in troubleshooting since we don't know what the woof_aq_resize function exactly does and it returns a uknown url, rather than a 404 one. Let me know what happens when you put this in.

Comment: It now comes up with a broken image link like this http://www.zilvertron.com/motoren/

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the img tag opening and closing, and also forgot the return is an array. Try this code now please and let me know.

Comment: Still the image is broken, GET http://www.zilvertron.com/motoren/$img_src[0] 404 (Not Found) if i inspect the item

Comment: `echo '$img_src[0]';` to `echo $img_src[0];` please, sorry I am sleepy, forgot to remove the `'` so it reads the variable as a string rather than taking it's value

Comment: Okay this shows the images, now i just need to resize them any easy workaround for that?

Comment: Glad I helped and glad you got it sorted, good luck with your project! :)